# Edit Margin and Position of Page Numbers in ClassThesis

Tags: classicthesis

- How to edit the margin of Page numbers to fill within the type area (Figure Below)? 
  [image]
- Some page numbers are placed in the footer (Figure below). How to keep all pagination in the header only?
  [image]

Comment: There's a line in `classicthesis.sty` that you can play with, just by adding it after the call to `classicthesis-config.tex` or `classicthesis.sty`, it reads `\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}}}`.  Something like `\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark\kern2em\small\pagemark}}}` should do the trick. As for the other question: where would you put those numbers on pages where there's no header (first page of a chapter, for example)?

Comment: Similarly for the other side, adjust `\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\pagemark\kern2em}\headmark\hfil}}`

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B The question seemed abandoned. Answering only the first part.

Answer (score 2):

There's a line in classicthesis.sty that you can play with, just by repeating it after the call to classicthesis-config.tex or classicthesis.sty; it reads `\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}}}`.

Something like `\rohead{\mbox{\hfil\headmark{\small\kern2em\pagemark}}} 
\lehead{\mbox{{\small\pagemark\kern2em}\headmark\hfil}}`
 should do the trick.

`\rohead` and `\lehead` are from the package scr­layer-scr­page of KOMA-Script.